establishing facts about constants in Dafny
Dafny neophyte here. I was expecting the assertion in use_a to pass:
class A {

  const a: int

  constructor(a0: int)
    requires a0 > 100
    ensures a > 100
  {
    a := a0;
  }

  function use_a(): bool
    reads this
  {
    assert a > 100;
    a > 200
  }

}

but the verifier says Error: assertion might not hold.
My real case creates a fairly involved constant from a constructor argument (a map with specific properties from a supplied list of items). I need to be able to establish some facts about that constant in the constructor, and use those in other places in the class.
I feel like I'm missing something here…

Update:
Based on the discussion below, I believe this is along the lines of what I want:
type vala = a: nat | a > 100 witness 101

class A {

  const a: vala

  constructor(a0: nat)
    requires a0 > 100
  {
    a := a0;
  }

  function use_a() : bool
  {
    assert a > 100;
    this.a > 200
  }

}


In Dafny, method and function verification happens according to preconditions.
Since there is no preconditions of use_a, a can be anything.
The way to do above in Dafny is following. Class is augmented with Valid predicate which is postcondition of constructor and every method and function requires and establishes Valid predicate.
class A {

  const a: int

  predicate Valid()
    reads this
  {
      this.a > 100
  }

  constructor(a0: int)
    requires a0 > 100
    ensures Valid()
  {
    a := a0;
  }

  function use_a() : bool
    reads this
    requires Valid()
  {
    assert a > 100;
    this.a > 200
  }

}
 


If that were the case, the why does this work when I use const a: int := 123 to initialise a instead. If we have to re-require that something is valid even though we know it is already both valid and immutable, then that seems like a very weak system.

When a const declaration has a RHS, then the verifier knows the value of the immutable field. But if the initialization of the const happens inside a constructor, then one would need a lot of inference to figure out what the value of the const is. (For example, the control flow in the constructor may be complicated, the constructor may call other methods in preparing the const's value, and there may be several constructors.) Therefore, in the general case, you need to use specifications to give you information about such a constant.

@RustanLeino I'm a little conncerned. If use_a was (hypothetically) going to be a function that was part of a library I was creating, then I haven't actually proven that the instance of A in always the correct state, I've only required that it must be. I can see by inspection that ensures Valid() is in the constructor, and a is a constant, and deduce it must be in the correct state, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of the extra effort of using a verifier in the first place?

@SamStainsby It sounds like you want a type where the property of the constant a always holds and you want to avoid writing requires Valid() everywhere. One way you can do that is (to remove the two reads this in @Divyanshu Ranjan's code above, and) to define type ValidA = a: A | a.Valid() witness * and function Use(va: ValidA): (result: int) ensures result > 100 { va.a }.  Then, export the type ValidA from your library.
